# Estimated number of rows is way off in execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-performance

I have a situation where the estimated number of rows in the execution plan is way off

[image]

My columns in the join are `varchar(50)`. I have tried different indexes but it does not reduce this problem. I have even tried with an index on the temp table. What else can I do?

PS this is the first place where the estimated number starts to drift... Also the tables are not big (48000 rows).

The code is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID
INTO #Households
FROM TableA

    
SELECT 
A.*,
MIN(B.[ProfileCreatedDate]) PROFILECREATEDDATE 
INTO #Profile
from #Households AS a 
LEFT JOIN TableA AS B
    
ON A.[HouseholdNumber]= B.[HouseholdNumber] and A.[HouseholdId]=B.[HouseholdId]
GROUP BY a.householdnumber, a.householdid, a.primaryCustomerID;
```

I know it seems that this can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID, MIN([ProfileCreatedDate]) AS PROFILECREATEDDATE 
INTO #Profile2
from TableA
GROUP BY householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID;
```

But the results are not identical and I don't want to change the results since I am not sure if the creator of this code knew what they were doing.

Some statistics on the columns:
`householdnumber` is always equal to `householdid`. `householdid` is `nvarchar(50)` but  `householdnumber` is `varchar(40)`. The table has 48877 rows. Distinct combination of `householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID` has 48029 rows. And distinct number of `primaryCustomerID` is 47152.

Comment: Without understanding everything that's going on, I'm not sure this is helpful, but: Are you aware you can run `UPDATE STATISTICS #Households` as part of your script? Or, probably better, add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your query (after the `GROUP BY` line).

Comment: @EdmCoff: Thanks I will try `UPDATE STATISTICS`. Actually I had tried recompile but that did not help either. I let you know if it works. But the table is just created ? I have to read more about statistics...

Comment: @EdmCoff: update statistics did not help...

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Comment: @HABO: I would love to but I am a bit paranoid to post something sensitive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the code - it appears that the difference between the larger (original) version and your simpler GROUP BY version is that the original finds the minimum `profilecreateddate` for *anyone* in that household, whereas your simpler version finds the `profilecreateddate` for the specific `primarycustomerid`.

For example (using simpler data)

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA (householdnumber int, householdid int, primaryCustomerID int, ProfileCreatedDate datetime);
INSERT INTO #TableA (householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID, ProfileCreatedDate) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '20201001'),
(1, 1, 1, '20201002'),
(1, 1, 2, '20201003');

SELECT DISTINCT householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID
INTO #Households
FROM #TableA;

SELECT 
    A.*,
    MIN(B.[ProfileCreatedDate]) PROFILECREATEDDATE 
INTO #Profile
from #Households AS a 
    LEFT JOIN #TableA AS B  
      ON A.[HouseholdNumber]= B.[HouseholdNumber] and A.[HouseholdId]=B.[HouseholdId]
GROUP BY a.householdnumber, a.householdid, a.primaryCustomerID;

SELECT * FROM #Profile;
/* -- Results
householdnumber  householdid  primaryCustomerID  PROFILECREATEDDATE
1                1            1                  2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
1                1            2                  2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
*/

SELECT householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID, MIN([ProfileCreatedDate]) AS PROFILECREATEDDATE 
INTO #Profile2
from #TableA
GROUP BY householdnumber, householdid, primaryCustomerID;

SELECT * FROM #Profile2;
/* -- Results
householdnumber  householdid  primaryCustomerID  PROFILECREATEDDATE
1                1            1                  2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
1                1            2                  2020-10-03 00:00:00.000
*/
```

If you notice in the above, the PROFILECREATEDATE for row 2 is different.

You could therefore try the following code that should give the same results as the original set - see how that goes for time (and confirm it matches the original results).

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.householdnumber, t1.householdid, primaryCustomerID, 
        MIN([ProfileCreatedDate]) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.householdnumber, t1.householdid) AS PROFILECREATEDDATE 
INTO #Profile3
FROM #TableA t1;

SELECT * FROM #Profile3;
/* -- Results
householdnumber  householdid  primaryCustomerID  PROFILECREATEDDATE
1                1            1                  2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
1                1            2                  2020-10-01 00:00:00.000
*/
```

Comment: You are right. Thanks! results are identical using `(SELECT * FROM #Profile EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #Profile2)
UNION all
(SELECT * FROM #Profile2 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM #Profile)`

Comment: It is super fast now. Took like 10 minuttes sometimes before now it finished in 2 seconds. But why are the estimates so far of in the original code?

Comment: +1 for adding the window function option, which should resolve the OPs original problem and also helps educate on how to utilise SQL Server to it's strengths

Comment: Regarding estimates - often it's not easy to work out what's going on, but remember that estimates are based only on a small amount of *metadata* without actually looking at the data. Often grouping throws estimates severely out because just has to take a guess how many come out (e.g., if grouping, let's guess that the result it will be 20% of the size). I don't 100% know (without looking at the execution plan as a whole) why it's so far out. The solution I had there a) minimises reads (only reads the table once) and then just groups at the end to minimise grouping causing multiplied errors.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Actually the window function method also makes more clear the intension of the code whereas the original code is difficult to understand. Anyway thanks.